# theta.sparse error with lorDIF

Tags: r

I was wondering whether anyone can help me out.
I am trying to run a dif analysis on my data but keep getting a theta.sparse error, which I am unsure of how to fix. I would really appreciate any that you can give me.

```
library(lordif)
dat<- read.csv2("OPSO.csv",header=TRUE)
datgender <- read.csv2("DATA.csv",header=TRUE)
group<-datgender$Gender
sink("outputDIFopso.txt")
gender.difopso <- lordif(dat, group, selection = NULL,
criterion = c("Chisqr", "R2", "Beta"),
pseudo.R2 = c("McFadden", "Nagelkerke", "CoxSnell"), alpha = 0.01,
beta.change = 0.1, R2.change = 0.02, maxIter = 10, minCell = 5,
minTheta = -4, maxTheta = 4, inc = 0.1, control = list(), model = "GRM",
anchor = NULL, MonteCarlo = FALSE, nr = 100)
print(gender.difopso)
summary(gender.difopso)
sink()
pdf("graphtestop.pdf")
plot(gender.difopso)
dev.off()
dev.off()
```

> Error in lordif(dat, group, selection = NULL, criterion = c("Chisqr",  : 
>     object 'theta.sparse' not found

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should check the error line before then. The output will probably say you have no items flagged for DIF. When that's the case you should just run the `mirt` function and extract `theta` and `ipar` objects as necessary.

The author *could* add some case handling for when `compare(flags, flags.matrix)` is true. At the very least, it seems a warning is omitted when there are no items with DIF the same way it says

```
 if (ndif == ni) {
      warning("all items got flagged for DIF - stopping\n")
    }
```

and there is no case handling when `(ndif == 0)` although `compare(flags, flag.matrix)` evaluates to `TRUE`.

The implications when all or none of the items have DIF is that you would get the same results (generating the same ICC plots, same inference etc) by fitting `mirt` in the combined sample (no DIF) or two or more `mirt` models for each group (all DIF). So it's a correct time saving procedure to just bypass when all that breaks down.